# pdb attach on subprocess when invoked as a script

Tags: python, pdb

I am trying to use ipdb be invoked as a script to debug other scripts.

For example:

`python3 -m pdb myscript.py`

using `multiprocessing.process`, I want pdb to automatically enter post-mortem debugging **attached to the subprocess** if the program being debugged exits abnormally.

However, when I run just `python3 -m pdb myscript.py`, although it raise and hung at some point without exiting, but does not enter into `post_mortem` mode.

---

update

I found that the probable problem is that child processes don't stop when any of their siblings raise unhandled exception and hang on post_mortem mode.
So what I want is if any of parent, or child processes stops, all of the processes to be stopped altogether.

I guess this part of code that spawning processes is troublesome. 
If it is, how should I change this to work it as I desired ?

```
for pid, funcs in enumerate(functions):
    procs.append(Process(target=subproc, args=pid, funcs))
    procs[-1].daemon = True
    procs[-1].start()
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the error-prone code in `with ipdb.slaunch_ipdb_on_exception():`?

Comment: I don't know how that `slaunch_ipdb_on_exception()` works and what it is doing, but when I wrapped and run the script, the error raised but keeps running the process.   
Such that   

```
log sth 1 
log sth 2 
log sth 3 
Process Process-2: 
Traceback(most recent call last):

... KeyError:'Key' 
log sth 4
log sth 5 ...
```
although I expect that the processs stops and hang on Traceback

Comment: @Ataxias behavior that I desired was to enter debugging mode in the middle of the run so that I can debug interactively on the shell.